# Recognizing a bluetooth connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'd like to start an application when a specific device BT is connected.

I do not want to use IFTTT, I'd like to write my own application able to autonomously implements what IFTTT does for any app: start when the event on bluetooth connection on device xxx is done.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to detect that smartphone is connected to a BLE device. You can do that in `BluetoothGattCallback`'s `onConnectionStateChange()` by checking wether `newState` is equal to `BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED`.

Then, start your target application's activity:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {

    if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED && status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        // start your target application's activity here
        Intent intent = new Intent(com.yourapp.ACTION);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: in order to have this event the app must be running, while I'd like to have somethings that opens the app closed... the scenario is i.e. when I go in my car and my phone connects to car bluetooth, start my application.